# Redirect 2 urls (%20) to one in nginx

Tags: nginx, url, redirect, spaces

I have this problem that I can't solve. I have a nginx server that I have to make a redirect of this type.

http://midomain.com/xxxx/xxxx/ http://wikipedia.com/xx --> http://midomain.com/yyyy

As I have two urls with a space, there is no way to make it work.

I have tried multiple ways.

```
rewrite ^/xxxx/xxxx/\ http://wikipedia.com/xx http://midomain.com/yyyy permanent;
rewrite "^/xxxx/xxxx/\ http://wikipedia.com/xx" http://midomain.com/yyyy permanent;
rewrite ^/xxxx/xxxx/%20http://wikipedia.com/xx http://midomain.com/yyyy permanent;
rewrite "^/xxxx/xxxx/%20http://wikipedia.com/xx" http://midomain.com/yyyy permanent;
rewrite ^/xxxx/xxxx/\ http://wikipedia.com/xx/$ http://midomain.com/yyyy permanent;
rewrite "^/xxxx/xxxx/\ http://wikipedia.com/xx/$" http://midomain.com/yyyy permanent;
rewrite ^/xxxx/xxxx/%20http://wikipedia.com/xx/$ http://midomain.com/yyyy permanent;
```

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx normalises the URI before processing it through `rewrite`. The `%20` is resolved to a literal space character and consecutive `/` characters are replace by a single `/`. It's that last point that's causing you problems.

For example:

```
rewrite "^/xxxx/xxxx/ http:/wikipedia\.com/xx$" http://midomain.com/yyyy permanent;
```